# jquery ui button doesn't fire after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, user-interface

I have this code running when I bind my events on page load:

```
$('span.removeItem','table').button();
```

When i run it in the callback of an ajax request it doesn't work.
It doesn't even run in the firebug console though it does correctly select the element.

Also tried:

```
$('span.removeItem','table').last().button();
```

to be sure there wasn't a conflict with preexisting buttons

The table row in the html if this helps:

```
<tr>
        <td class="item">fsdfsdfsdf<span class="removeItem">X</span>
        </td>
        <td class="solution">
            <input itemId="372" solution=""/>
            <span itemId="372" timestamp="1337806132"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="actions">
            <span class="edit hidden">Update</span>
            <span class="save shown">Save</span>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Adding the success callback":

```
success: function(data) {
                self.addNewItem(data);
        $('span.removeItem','table').last().button();

}
```

Comment: Do you have the jQuery UI button call in your AJAX callback?

Comment: yes the code above is in the callback. I am using both bootstrap and jquery ui so there might be something with that though I don't see why.

Comment: There is a clash with the bootstrap js as it works when I removed those files to test

Comment: The solution is to not use the bootstrap button.js with jquery ui.
Simple. :) I cannot answer this post myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you use:

```
$('span.removeItem','table').button();
```

But you don't have an element that originally contains a class of `removeItem`

Try looking at live()

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I do but I just noticed that when I removed that line from the bindEvents call that is fired on page load running it in firebug doesn't work even though thee are 3 rows with spans of that class